# How to make the return of my new pyhon class working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

for school I have to make a chained list in python with all the useful command. I made it with a friend on his windows computer and it work well.
The problem is, when i launch it on Linux, on Arch or on my Debian docker, it return :

```
>>> A= Liste(1,2,3,4,3,5,6,7)
>>> A
<Liste.Liste object at 0x7f26a0903278>
```

I can copy-paste the code, but as a french, my professor don't want that I write my code in English.

```py
class Liste: #création de la classe


#initialisation de l'objet
    def __init__(self, *elements):
        self.list = [None, None] #inititialisation de la liste
        for element in elements: #pour chaque élémment de la liste
            if self.list[0] == None: #si le 1er élément la liste est vide
                self.list[0] = element #le 1er élement de la liste devient élément
                suivant = self.list #et suivant deviens la liste
            else:
                suivant[1] = [element, None] #sinon, le 2e élément de la liste devient [élément, None]
                suivant = suivant[1] #et suivant avance dans la liste chainée

#ajouter un élément à la liste
    def ajouter(self, element):
        suivant = self.list #suivant devient la liste
        while suivant[1] != None: #tant que le deuxième émént du duo n'est pas None
            suivant = suivant[1] #suivant avance dans la liste chainée
        suivant[1] = [element, None] #quand suivant à atteind le None, il remplace le None par l'élément

#inserer un élément dans une liste à un indice donné
    def inserer(self, index, element):
        suivant = self.list #suivant devient la liste
        for _ in range(index-1): #on atteind le
            suivant = suivant[1] #bon rang
        suivant[1] = [element, suivant[1]] #on insère le bon élément à la bonne place

#acceder à un rang particulier
    def acceder(self, index):
        suivant = self.list #suivant devient la liste
        for _ in range(index): #on atteind le bon rang
            suivant = suivant[1]
        return suivant[0]

#longueur de la liste avec len
    def __len__(self):
        suivant = self.list #suivant devient la liste
        i = 0 #on crée un indice pour compter
        if self.list[0] == None: #si le première élément du duo est vaut None
            return i #la liste fait i éléments
        else:
            while suivant[1] != None: #sinon, tant que la dervière valeur du duo n'est pas nulle
                i +=  1 # i prend un point en plus
                suivant = suivant[1] #et on avance dans la liste
        return i+1 # et on retourne i+1

#supprimer un valeur à un indice donné
    def supprimer_ind(self, index):
        suivant = self.list #suivant devient la liste
        for _ in range(index-1): #on se déplace
            suivant = suivant[1] #jusqu'à l'élément que l'on veut supprimer
        suivant[1] =  suivant[1][1] #et on l'écrase avec la valeur suivante

#pour remplacer la liste
    def remplacer(self, index, valeur):
        suivant = self.list #On lui donne la valeur de la liste
        for _ in range(index): #on se déplace
            suivant = suivant[1] #jusqu'à l'élément que l'on veut modifier
        suivant[0] = valeur #et on modifie la valeur

    def supprimer_val(self, valeur):
        ancien = None
        suivant = self.list #On lui donne la valeur de la liste
        while suivant[0] != valeur: #tant que la valeur de suivant[0] n'est pas égale à la valeur demandée,
            ancien = suivant #on sauvegarde suivant
            suivant = suivant[1] #et on avance dans la liste
        if ancien == None: #si ancien est vide, alors on supprime la premiève valeur
            suivant[0] = suivant[1][0]
            suivant[1] = suivant[1][1]
        else:
            ancien[1] = suivant[1] #sinon, on remplace ancien par suivant[1]

#on vide la liste
def vider(self):
    self.list = [None, None] #on remet à zéro la valeur de la liste

    def __repr__(self):
        suivant = self.list #suivant devient la liste
        objet = "|"
        while suivant[1] != None: #tant que le deuxième émént du duo n'est pas None
            objet += str(suivant[0]) + ", "
            suivant = suivant[1] #suivant avance dans la liste chainée
        objet += str(suivant[0]) + "|"
        return f'{objet}'
```

Comment: Is this your actual indentation? ``def vider(self):`` is not indented, putting it outside class scope and making ``__repr__`` a function local to ``vider`` instead of a method.

Comment: Please note that SO official communication language is English. Make sure that code samples are also in that language, if you want to enable more people to help you out.

Comment: Sorry about your professor. _Forcing_ people to write non-English code is just bad form. (I'd understand _allowing_ non-English code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__repr__` magic is responsible for object representation formatting. You've messed up the indentation in `def vider ...` line. Here is a quickfix:

```py
    #on vide la liste
    def vider(self):
        self.list = [None, None] #on remet à zéro la valeur de la liste

    def __repr__(self):
        suivant = self.list #suivant devient la liste
        objet = "|"
        while suivant[1] != None: #tant que le deuxième émént du duo n'est pas None
            objet += str(suivant[0]) + ", "
            suivant = suivant[1] #suivant avance dans la liste chainée
        objet += str(suivant[0]) + "|"
        return f'{objet}'
```

`Liste(1, 2, 3)` returns `|1, 2, 3|`, as expected.

Comment: Please don't add full answers to typo questions. These questions are on-topic, but they are unlikely to help future readers, and they should be closed as such. Leaving full answers to typos hinders automatic deletion processes.

Comment: @AndrasDeak is it better now or should I remove code section entirely?

Comment: No, the problem is not _how_ you answer it. It can be the most brilliant answer in the world but still if it's posted on a typo, it's a waste of your efforts :)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Ok, I see, thanks for clarification

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I guess I didn't read enough my code... Sorry for the inconvenience !